# How to calculate the characteristic exponents

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I'm trying to solve the following question:

Q: Let $Q(t)>0$ be a $C^1$ period function on $\mathbb R$, show that the solution of equation $x''(t)-Q(t)x=0$ is not bounded.

I tried to solve it by the Floquet theory. The above equation corresponds to a $2\times2$ period matrix $A(t)=(0, 1, Q(t),0)$(I don't know how to type matrix ,here 0 and 1 forms the first row, -Q(t) and 0 forms the second row). Then Floquet's theorem tells us that if the characteristic exponents has non-zero real part then the solution of the original equation is unbounded. Is there a good method to calculate the  characteristic exponents? Or there are different method for my original question ?

Comment: As $Q$ is not periodic, how do you intend to apply Floquet theory? You could start your exploration with the WKB approximation.

Comment: Thanks for you correction and advice.  I missed an $x$ and Q is periodic. Then will Floquet theory works?

Comment: Yes, but you get a faster result using $0<m^2\le Q(t)\le M^2<\infty$ and then using comparison theorems. Or just something like: if $x(t_1)>0$ and $x'(t_1)>0$, then due to the convexity of the solution for $t>t_1$ the solution grows faster than the tangent.

Comment: Thanks, but how to use comparision theorems to second order equations? As far as I know, it tells about one order equation.

Comment: The Sturm-Picone comparison theorem for oscillating solutions in the "elliptical" case has also a companion or corollary for the "hyperbolic" case, in that any solution can have at most one root. Also, unrelated, note that $x''-x=0$ has forwards bounded solutions $x=ce^{-t}$, so you need some really global argument for the claim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On solution segments where $x(t)$ is positive (negative), one has by the DE $x''(t)>0$ ($<0$), so the curve is convex (concave).

This has immediately the consequence that any non-trivial $x(t)$ can have at most one root, as any arc between two consecutive roots becomes impossible.

If $x(t_*)=0$ with $x'(t_*)>0$, then by convexity the solution for $t>t_*$ has to be above the tangent at $t_*$ locally on some small segment, meaning the solution stays positive there, which prolongs this property globally for all $t>t_*$.

As non-zero constant solutions are impossible, for any positive solution one can find a point with a non-horizontal tangent which forces the solution to $\infty$ in one direction.

For solutions with negative values, note that with $x(t)$ also $-x(t)$ is a solution.